# Meteor deploys successfully to EC2 using MUP but doesn't display anything

Tags: amazon-ec2, meteor, meteor-up

Meteor 0.8.2

I have a Meteor app that deploys successfully using `meteor deploy`. It also runs successfully locally, even after I do a `meteor reset` and I start the local server back up.

I'm using Meteor Up to deploy to EC2 and deployment says that it was successful.

`mup setup` completes just fine and my Node version is

```
"nodeVersion": "0.10.28"
```

The correct version of node was also verified on the EC2 server via SSH.

I'm able to go into the Mongo console on the EC2 server and view my collections as well.

`[ec2-54-241-5-181.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] ✔ Invoking deployment process: SUCCESS`

`mup logs -f`

```
[ec2-54-241-5-181.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-241-5-181.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com,54.241.5.181' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
[ec2-54-241-5-181.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com]  >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to gid: meteoruser
 >> stepping down to uid: meteoruser
```

But when I go to `ec2-54-241-5-181.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` nothing shows up. The page is entirely blank.

Is there any way for me to view Meteor's server logs via SSH on the EC2? I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: have you resolved this? im facing a similar issue

Comment: Sorry, I *think* I may have resolved it, but it's been so long that I honestly don't know how I did it. Have you updated both Iron Router and Meteor to the latest versions?

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your app, if you load your browser's js console up you would see the error:

```
Exception in defer callback: Error: No uiManager configured on Router
```

This can happen sometimes if you have not run `mrt update` or have modified your `smart.json`, and its missing the `blaze-layout` package (if you're on Meteor 0.8.0+).

This error is preventing your router from working and displaying your page. The app has deployed successfully though, besides this error somewhere in your code.

More information about this specific error on github too: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/449

Comment: i'm on meteor 1.0.2. do we need iron-router to use mup?

Comment: @blue_zinc no iron-router is independent of mup, one doesn't notice the other.